# How to make a preamp that is ON when input is a MIC but OFF when a LINE level?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, amplifier, gain, preamp

My question is very simple:

Is there a way to create a "preamp" circuit that is automatically ON when there is a MIC connected (for example, a desktop PC microphone) but OFF when there is a LINE connected (for example, some mp3 player?)

[By the way, here I found some "preamps."](https://www.homemade-circuits.com/small-amplifier-circuit)

Comment: yes, there is a way.

Comment: How would the preamp "know" what type of device is connected? If the only difference is the signal level then a reliable detection cannot be done. If the signal is line level but temporarily muted (like in between tracks) so the preamp is switched on, then the music starts at normal level but the preamp isn't switched off yet.

Comment: How would you tell the difference between LINE (but no signal) and MIC?